# Python - Tkinter Double and UNDO Button

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

I am new to python and just wrote a little script which substract numbers from a "Start-Number".
Actually it's working without functionality of Button4 and Button5.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from functools import partial
    #Create Window
    app= tk.Tk()
    #Create Start Number
    Zahl = tk.Label(app, text="50",font="Verdana 20 bold")
    def change_zahl(num):
        counter = int(str(Zahl['text']))
        counter -=num
        Zahl.config(text=str(counter))
    #Create Buttons and pack them(Button4 and Button 5 do nothing till now :(
    Button1 = tk.Button(app, text="-1", command=partial(change_zahl, 1)).pack()
    Button2 = tk.Button(app, text="-2", command=partial(change_zahl, 2)).pack()
    Button3 = tk.Button(app, text="-3", command=partial(change_zahl, 3)).pack()
    Button4 = tk.Button(app, text="double next pressed button").pack()
    Button5 = tk.Button(app, text="UNDO action from last pressed button").pack()
    #Pack Start Number
    Zahl.pack()
    #mainloop
    app.mainloop()
```

I don't know how I can create a function for Button 4, which doubles the value of the next pressed button. I reached that with checkboxes, but they look ugly imho and I don't get it with a simple button, dunno.

Besides I have no idea what to do to undo the action of any button by pressing button UNDO.

I am happy for any help, hint, solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable `double=False` and assign it `True` only when the `button4` is pressed. If `double = True` then assign  `counter -= (num*2)`.

For the undo button, you might have to store each counter value into a list.

Here is a demonstration:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
    #Create Window
app= tk.Tk()
#Create Start Number

Zahl = tk.Label(app, text="50",font="Verdana 20 bold")

undo=[50] # your first number goes here
double_num = False

def undo_action():

    if len(undo) >= 2:
 
        counter = int(Zahl['text']) + (undo[-2] - undo[-1])  
        Zahl.config(text=str(counter))
        undo.pop(-1)
    

def double():
    global double_num
    double_num = True

def change_zahl(num):
        global double_num
        counter = int(Zahl['text'])
        if double_num:
            counter -= (num*2)
            double_num = False

        else:
            counter -= num

        undo.append(counter)
        Zahl.config(text=str(counter))
        
#Create Buttons and pack them(Button4 and Button 5 do nothing till now :(

Button1 = tk.Button(app, text="-1", command=partial(change_zahl, 1)).pack()
Button2 = tk.Button(app, text="-2", command=partial(change_zahl, 2)).pack()
Button3 = tk.Button(app, text="-3", command=partial(change_zahl, 3)).pack()
Button4 = tk.Button(app, text="double next pressed button", command=double).pack()
Button5 = tk.Button(app, text="UNDO action from last pressed button", command=undo_action).pack()
#Pack Start Number
Zahl.pack()
#mainloop
app.mainloop()
```

*on a side note: `pack()` returns `None` which means all your buttons are assigned `None`. So instead create an instance in one line and use `pack` in another.*

Comment: I really appreciate your demonstration and try to transfer it to my other program! Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Checkbutton` with `indicator=0` for the <kbd>Double</kbd> button which will look like a button.

Also suggest to assign an `IntVar` to label `Zahl` so that it can be updated more easier.

For *undo* function, you can create a list to hold the history values.  Then you can go back to last value when <kbd>Undo</kbd> is clicked.

Below is updated code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

history = []  # store history values

def change_zahl(num):
    if double_var.get():
        num += num
    val = counter.get()
    counter.set(val-num)
    history.append(val) # store last value to history

def undo():
    if history:
        val = history.pop()
        counter.set(val)

app = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(app, text="-1", command=partial(change_zahl, 1)).pack()
tk.Button(app, text="-2", command=partial(change_zahl, 2)).pack()
tk.Button(app, text="-3", command=partial(change_zahl, 3)).pack()
double_var = tk.BooleanVar()
tk.Checkbutton(app, text="Double", variable=double_var, indicator=0).pack()
tk.Button(app, text="Undo", command=undo).pack()

counter = tk.IntVar(value=50)
Zahl = tk.Label(app, textvariable=counter, font="Verdana 20 bold")
Zahl.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for your example, i will try If indicator=0 works for me and propably add IntVar to Label Zahl. Thank you